# Maximise $L^q$ norm of a vector, for fixed $L^1$ and fixed $L^p$ norms

Tags: inequalities, oc.optimization-and-control

Consider a vector $x \in \mathbb R_+^n$ and $p,q \in \mathbb R$ such that 
$1 < p < q$

We fix $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}|x_i| = 1$ and $ \left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p} = \theta < 1$.

In other words, $x$ is a probability mass function, with a fixed $p$-norm.

The question is to find that $x$ which maximises the $q$-norm i.e. maximises $\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^q \right)^\frac{1}{q}$.

*Some observations:*

1. If $q = \infty$, the problem reduces to finding that $x$ which has the largest value for $\sup \limits_i \; x(i)$ leading to the distribution which looks like $\left( \alpha, \frac{1-\alpha}{n-1}, \frac{1-\alpha}{n-1}, \ldots, \frac{1-\alpha}{n-1} \right)$.
2. Using perturbation arguments (Lagrangian multipliers), it can be shown that $x$ can take at most $2$ distinct non-zero values in its co-ordinates. This reduces the problem to a finite number of cases.

My guess is that the distribution $\left( \alpha, \frac{1-\alpha}{n-1}, \frac{1-\alpha}{n-1}, \ldots, \frac{1-\alpha}{n-1} \right)$ which works for $q = \infty$ should also work for all $q > p$. It seems intuitively true and matlab calculations also support this guess. Any pointers/related problems/inequalities are very much welcome.

Comment: You will find an answer to a more general question here http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=33456&hilit=equal+variable+principle

Comment: A very similar question is considered in:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910093

Comment: This is a nice question but rather elementary for MO.  Since the OP has been pointed in the right direction, I vote to close.

Comment: This is exactly what I had been searching for. Thanks! Just for the sake of completion, link to the proof of Equal variable theorem: http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf